# Как решить эту простую задачу?

Tags: python

Не до конца понимаю принцип работы этих циклов. Что нужно вставить в пустые места для правильной работы программы?

```
def square(n):
    return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
    sum = 0
    for n in ___:
        sum += __
    return __

print(sum_squares(10)) # Должно выводить 285
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код реализует алгоритм получения суммы квадратов чисел в промежутке от 0 до 9.

1. **Не называйте переменные именами объектов**, так как имена зарезервированы питоном.
2. Если вы не знаете принцип работы циклов, то переходить к принципу работы функций не стоит, так как это базовые знания.
3. `for n in ___:` здесь вы должны подставить число, по которому будет происходить итерация, то есть напишите так: `for i in range(x)`, где `x` - аргумент функции `sum_squares`
4. Здесь `sum += __` вы должны вызвать функцию для сложения квадратов чисел `n`: `sum_x += square(n)`, где `sum_x` - `sum`.
5. `return sum_x` возвращаем результат функции.

Полный код:

```
def square(n):
    return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
    sum_x = 0
    for n in range(x):
        sum_x += square(n)
    return sum_x

print(sum_squares(10)) # Должно выводить 285
```